# Rewrite stored procedure to remove cursors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm attempting to remove the cursors from this stored procedure but not sure of the Best latest best practise for this kind of operational to run in a efficient statement.

Can anyone offer any pseudo code on what to implement to eliminate these from a Dev perspective?

```
    --Generate the channel date from a specified date
DECLARE @ConvDate DATETIME
SET @ConvDate = DateAdd(day,-100,getDate())
WHILE DateDiff(day,GetDate(), @ConvDate ) < 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC mltGenerateChannelData @ConvDate
    SET @ConvDate = DateAdd(day, 1, @ConvDate)
END


        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mltGenerateChannelData] (@ConvDate DATETIME)  AS  
        BEGIN  

           DECLARE @ChannelId INT, 
           @URLSignature Varchar(30), 
           @RawSQL VARCHAR(2000), 
           @SQLQuery VARCHAR(4000), 
           @ThisUTMId BIGINT 

           DECLARE cursChannels CURSOR STATIC FOR 
            SELECT 
                ChannelId, 
                URLSignature, 
                RawSQL  
            FROM dbo.TrackingChannel_tbl (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE ProcessVisitDate = 1  

            SET @ConvDate = dbo.datePart_fn(@ConvDate)  

         --Clear out any existing data for this conversion date  
         DELETE FROM TrackingChannelDailyTotal_tbl 
         WHERE TrackingDate = @ConvDate  

         OPEN cursChannels  

         FETCH cursChannels INTO @ChannelId, @URLSignature, @RawSQL  

         CREATE TABLE #UTM 
         (trpUTMID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
         TotalMArgin MONEY, 
         RawURLRequest Varchar(2000), 
         Keywords VARCHAR(1000), 
         VisitDate DATETIME, 
         RefererURL VARCHAR(2000))  

         INSERT INTO #UTM (trputmid, TotalMargin)  
            SELECT trpUTMID, SUM(b.TotalMArgin)  
            FROM TrackingConversion_tbl c(NOLOCK), Booking_tbl b(NOLOCK)               
            WHERE c.BookingId = b.BookingId  
            AND c.BookedDate >= @ConvDate  
            GROUP BY trputmid  

         UPDATE u  
            SET RawURLRequest = v.RawURLRequest,  
             Keywords = v.Keywords,  
                   VisitDate = v.VisitDate,  
                   RefererURL = v.RefererURL  
             FROM #UTM u,    
            TrackingVisit_tbl (NOLOCK)  v   
         WHERE v.trpUTMID = u.trpUTMId  

         CREATE TABLE #UTM2  (trpUTMID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY)  

         WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
         BEGIN  

           Print 'Processing Channel Id : ' + Convert(varchar(10), @ChannelId)  

           TRUNCATE TABLE #UTM2  


           SET @SQLQuery = ' INSERT INTO #UTM2 (trpUTMId)  
                             SELECT u.TrpUTMId  
                             FROM #UTM u               
                             WHERE u.VisitDate >= ''' + COnvert(varchar,@ConvDate) + '''   
                             AND u.VisitDate < DateAdd(day,1,''' + Convert(varchar,@ConvDate) + ''') '  


           IF @URLSignature <> ''  
           BEGIN              
            SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'AND u.RawURLRequest like ''%' + @URLSignature + '%'' '    
           END  

           IF @RawSQL <> ''  
           BEGIN  
            SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + @RawSQL  
           END  

           EXEC (@SQLQuery)  

           INSERT INTO TrackingChannelDailyTotal_tbl (ChannelId, TrackingDate, Conversions, TotalMargin)  
            SELECT @ChannelId, @ConvDate, Count(u1.trpUTMID), IsNUll(SUM(TotalMargin),0)  
            FROM #UTM u1, #UTM2 u2  
            WHERE u1.TRputmid = u2.trputmid  


           FETCH cursChannels INTO @ChannelId, @URLSignature, @RawSQL  

         END  

         CLOSE cursChannels  
         DEALLOCATE cursChannels
```

Comment: Is there a specific area you are stuck on?  Posting a long block of code with no context about what it does or what you need specific help on is not the best approach to ask a question.

Comment: I guess just rewriting one of the cursors so I can view the transformation and then attempt the others. Apologies only joined this week as a DBA so the system is very new to me as well

Comment: Start from the inside out; rewrite the cursor in the middle as a set-based approach, and go from there.  Work it out a little at a time.

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: thanks for the constructive advice, without boring people with the details I was up against it in 2-3 hours with no test system and was struggling to compare the results as the whole process was taking 7 hours.                                                              It was a long evening, I got there in the end, breaking it into chunks to temp tables on a sandbox db. It was a good experience to improve my coding for a production DBA. I didn't finish it in time to stop the job failing or getting flack, that was the only reason I posted such a piece of code. thanks for the down vote though!

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSMS Tools (http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) and 'Include Actual Execution plan' with the query, you can break down the bottle-necks in the query, take each part and try to isolate and improve the query.

You may find that the issue is with a different part of the query, and not the cursor.

Comment: thanks, I have that tool, I also used SQL sentry query plan tool & the additional SQL server snap in (both free), which makes the plan alot more readable and can highlight areas that need focus

Answer (score -1):

if by old server you mean low memory or processing power
and if it is feasible to upgrade the hardware
being a DBA i will suggest  to upgrade the hardware.